# Fastest way to parse all Excel formulas using Python 3.5

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

As part of a bigger set of tests I need to extract all the formulas within an uploaded Excel workbook.  I then need to parse each formula into its respective range references and dump those references into a simple database.  For example, if Cell A1 has a formula =B1 + C1 then my database would record B1 and C1 as referenced cells.

Currently I read formulas one at a time using openpyxl and then parse them.  This is fine for smaller workbooks, but for large workbooks it can be very slow.  It feels entirely inefficient.

Could pandas or a similar module extract Excel formulas faster?  Or is there perhaps a better way to extract all workbook formulas than reading it one cell at a time?

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I did do a search on pandas' capabilities and it seems it can't do what I want, but I haven;t used it much and may have missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "extracting the formulae faster"? They are stored with each cell so you have to go cell by cell. When it comes to parsing, openpyxl includes a tokeniser which you might find useful. In theory this would allow you to read the worksheet XML files directly and only parse the nodes with formulae in them. However, you'd also have to handle the "shared formulae" that some applications use. openpyxl automatically converts such formulae into per-cell ones.

Internally Pandas relies on xlrd to read the files, so the ETL of getting the stuff into Pandas won't be faster than working directly with worksheet objects.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Charlie. I want to ensure that my tests run as fast as they could and sometimes find some performance issues with large spreadsheets.  I make extensive use of the Tokenizer (great work by the way, very handy).  I didn't dig too deeply into how Pandas works - based on its performance on a massive CSV file I processed a while ago, I thought it may have some other magic by which is gets its speed.  However, if getting the formulas cell by cell is the only way then perhaps that is as far as I can make it.

Comment: CSV is a much easier format to parse. It's also completely untyped. If you can use openpyxl's parser directly then you can avoid the not inconsiderable overhead of creating cells but note that we don't consider the parsers to be part of a public API.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about python, but a fast approach to the problem is:

- get all the formulas in R1C1 mode into an array using specialcells
- feed into a collection/dictionary to get uniques
- then parse the uniques

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  R1C1 unfortunately won't work as the database will be used partly to map reference dependencies.  My current approach delivers an acceptable result, but my problem is one of optimization.

Comment: How do you expect to collect the uniques without parsing the file?

Comment: @artifex_knowledge -you can collect in R1C1 to get uniques and then convert to A1 if required.

Comment: @Charlie Clarke _ in R1C1 Mode copied formulas are all the same - in A1 mode they are not - that is why every formula auditing tool that looks for unique formulas starts by getting R1C1 formulas into an array (reading cell-by-cell is extremely slow) then adding the formulas from the array to a collection/dictionary to get uniques. Then parse the R1C1 or convert it back to A1 and then parse. Getting reference dependencies/precedents from the parsed tokens is also non-trivial because of implicit and explicit intersection and functions (native+UDFs) that return references etc

Comment: That's interesting to note but doesn't really help in this context: openpyxl does not support that kind of notation. There may be more specialised tools for this kind of thing.

Comment: OK: I had not checked out the capabilities of OpenPyXL. Sticking with Python something like PyXLL would probably perform faster for this task. Or choose some other language that allows for tighter integration with Excel and exposes more of Excel's function.

Comment: @Charles Williams - As a general point I developed an R1C1 mapper to assist in seeking formula inconsistencies which is a far superior method to check offsets. I therefore have the capability.  However, in this specific case I need the duplicates as I am mapping cell dependencies.